# C#: given type alias X, why I can't use List<X> in a definition of another type alias?

Tags: c#, using

C# compiler (Visual Studio 2019, C# 7.3) does not like using an aliased type as a generic argument of another aliased type. I looked in C# language spec, and there seems to be no explicit prohibition against that. Is it a bug or a feature?

```
// C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foo
{
    using IntPair = Tuple<int,int>;
    using IntPairList = List<IntPair>; // does not compile: IntPair is not found
    
    class Bar
    {
        static List<IntPair> list; // compiles OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [section in the spec about using directives in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#1351-general) (emphasis mine),

> The scope of a `using_directive` extends over the `namespace_member_declarations` of its immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body. The scope of a `using_directive` **specifically does not include its peer** `using_directives`. Thus, peer `using_directives` do not affect each other, and the order in which they are written is insignificant.

In short, you cannot make use of the effect of other `using`s in the same "scope" (I'm using this word very loosely here), when writing a `using` directive.

More examples:

```
using System;
// using IntPair = Tuple<int,int>; // Not OK, can't use the effect of "using System;" here!
using IntPair = System.Tuple<int,int>; // OK
```

```
using IntPair = System.Tuple<int,int>;
namespace Foo
{
    // OK, "IntPair" is introduced in a parent "scope", not the Foo namespace
    using IntPairList = List<IntPair>;
}
```